# Batch create folders from TXT file... with subfolders in them

Tags: macos, terminal, batch-processing, automator

I have a TXT file with 1,000 lines of product numbers I need to make into 1,000 folders with two subfolders in each named IMAGE & SPEC. I want to run it in Automator or from Terminal on my mac but cannot find the answer ANYWHERE! Any help out there?

Comment: So is your answer Jeremy through automator? That is where I am lost. I have the products.txt file but don't know where to start in automator, is it a workflow, application, etc.... How do you point the automator to the folder and get the outputted 1,000 folder result with subfolders in each?

Comment: This question is too complex to explain here in text, because there various steps to apply in automator, but automator have a completely documentation check here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/AutomatorConcepts/Articles/ShellScriptActions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002078-BCIBAEAC, and then use one scripts from answers posteds bellow.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pure shellscript for this task like below:

```sh
while read line; 
do 
  mkdir -p "$line/IMAGE";  
  mkdir -p "$line/SPEC";  
done < products.txt
```

Comment: Yeah, it's rigth an txt file can take infinite formats and the question hasn't clearly abourt this. My solution is an scratch, and maybe him should be implements more things like cut's ....

Answer (score 0):

In Terminal.app, type “cd “ (without the quotes but make sure there is a space after `cd`). Then drag the folder from Finder (the folder where you want the 1000 new folders created in) Into Terminal.app.  This will change the working directory to the directory to where the new folders will be created.

If your products.txt file is located in the same directory as the 1000 new folders will be created, enter this following line of code into the Terminal window and be sure to change the name “products.txt” to your actual file name.

```
while read line; do mkdir -p "$line/IMAGE"; mkdir -p "$line/SPEC"; done < products.txt
```

If your products.txt file is located elsewhere, then use this line of code instead.

```
while read line; do mkdir -p "$line/IMAGE"; mkdir -p "$line/SPEC"; done <
```

then drag the “products.txt” file from Finder Into Terminal.app.  Then it should look something like this (assuming the “products.txt” file was on you Desktop)

```
while read line; do mkdir -p "$line/IMAGE"; mkdir -p "$line/SPEC"; done < /Users/YourShortName/Desktop/products.txt
```